# Why are inversions defined as the reverse complement and not just the reverse of the reference?

Tags: ngs, structural-variation

I can’t quite understand the way inversions are defined. In particular I expect an inversion to be only a reversed version of the reference and not its reverse complement. Most sources use diagrams such as below which totally obscure the fact that it is also complemented.

[image]

Could someone provide an explanation on what causes an inversion and why it is defined the way it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an inversion were just reversed then there would be 3' -> 3' bonds and 5' -> 5' bonds. That's why inversions are reverse complemented, you then maintain the normal 5'->3' direction. This is nicely covered [over on our biology sister site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44550/how-to-read-this-dna-inversion-diagram), which also includes this image:

[image: DNA inversion]

Comment: Thanks for the link. The image you posted made it clear for me. The key is to look at both strands at the same time.